# htaccess redirect everything from subfolder to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'll redirect everything from my subfolder `domain.com/zh` to another domain like `domain-china.com/zh` but this isn't working ... my attempts were:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com/zh/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://domain-china.com/zh/$0 [L,NE,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com/zh$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain-china.com/zh/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I'm also need everything from querystring, f.e.
`domain.com/zh/product-xyz` should rewrite into `domain-china.com/zh/product-xyz` and my folder `/zh` is only a virtural folder from my TYPO3 CMS (default language: domain.com; english: domain.com/en; chinese domain.com/zh; ...). There's no subfolders in my file structure at webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `HTTP_HOST` only matches host name not the URI. For that you can use pattern in `RewriteRule` like this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^zh/.*$ https://domain-china.com/$0 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Perfect. I also need `RewriteRule ^zh/.*$ https://domain-china.com/$0 [L,NC,NE,R=301]`